# How to EnableRetryOnFailure inside Unit of Work TransactionScope?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, transactionscope

Say I have the following `UnitOfWork` which can be injected into handlers and used to perform db operations within `TransactionScope`:

```
internal sealed class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly TransactionScope _transactionScope;

    public UnitOfWork(IOptions<UnitOfWorkOptions> options)
    {
        EnsureArg.IsNotNull(options, nameof(options));

        _transactionScope = new TransactionScope(
            TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
            new TransactionOptions
            {
                IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
                Timeout = TransactionManager.DefaultTimeout,
            },
            TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);
    }

    Task CompleteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _transactionScope.Complete();
        Dispose(true);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
        => Dispose(true);

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _transactionScope.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In my handlers:

```
public MyHandler(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IRepository repository)
{
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    _repository = repository;
}

public async Task HandleAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var entity = await _repository.GetItem(cancellationToken);
    await _unitOfWork.CompleteAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

After enabling ef core's [connection resilience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency) with `EnableRetryOnFailure` I get this annoying error whenever any transactions occur within my unit of work:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The configured execution strategy 'SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy' does not support user-initiated transactions. Use the execution strategy returned by 'DbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy()' to execute all the operations in the transaction as a retriable unit.'

So I injected my `DbContext` and tried passing my db code into `CompleteAsync` to wrap it around an execution strategy, but the same error still persists:

```
Task CompleteAsync(Func<Task> action, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var strategy = _dbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
    return strategy.ExecuteAsync(
        async () =>
        {
            await action();
            _transactionScope.Complete();
            Dispose(true); 
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
}
```

Handler:

```
public async Task HandleAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var task = new Func<Task>(async () =>
    {
        var entity = await _repository.GetItem(cancellationToken);
    });
    await _unitOfWork.CompleteAsync(task, cancellationToken);
}
```

I also tried simply wrapping the `_transactionScope.Complete();` in the execution strategy but unsurprisingly it did not help

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: What are you passing in as the `action` parameter? Also, you don't need the `return Task.CompletedTask;` line in an `async` method.

Comment: `action` could be any number of database operations which are executed in the transaction scope @RichardDeeming I added a very simple example of what it may look like before passing into an extended `CompleteAsync` method

Comment: It needs to be *all* actions that touch the database - everything from the first query to load or add data up to and including the `SaveChangesAsync` call.

Comment: @RichardDeeming Yes all of those get passed in as `task`

Comment: EF is already wrapping your changes in a transaction, there is no need for you to wrap it again.  If you are doing non-EF database things within your handlers, stop it (or don't use ANY ef in those handlers).

Comment: @Neil I'm not trying to wrap it in a transaction, I am trying to wrap it in an execution strategy as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency where you will notice that a transaction is wrapped inside a `ExecuteAsync`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working like this

```
Task CompleteAsync(Func<Task> action, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var strategy = _dbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
    return strategy.ExecuteAsync(
        async () =>
        {
            using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
            {
                await action();
                transaction.Complete();
                Dispose(true); 
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        });
}
```

So instead of initialisting `TransactionScope` in the constructor, it gets created at the last minute, and is wrapped in the execution strategy

They do actually do this in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency#execution-strategies-and-transactions):

```
using (var context1 = new BloggingContext())
{
    context1.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Url = "http://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio" });

    var strategy = context1.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();

    strategy.Execute(
        () =>
        {
            using (var context2 = new BloggingContext())
            {
                using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    context2.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Url = "http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnet" });
                    context2.SaveChanges();

                    context1.SaveChanges();

                    transaction.Complete();
                }
            }
        });
}
```